# Please merge google-oauth and google-oauth2

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[google-oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-oauth) and [google-oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-oauth2) have the exact same tag description and are both about oauthv2, should they be synonymised ?
Please note I’m not suggesting what should be the target synonym… but I’d make sure that the icon of [google-oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-oauth2) should be kept if [google-oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-oauth) become the main tag.

Comment: google oauth is deprecated. Questions tagged with it can't do anything for future visitors

Comment: @SagarV : that’s why [tag:google-oauth] is about oauth2 not v1. Did you read the description ?

Comment: Added [tag:support] as it requires moderator assistance and the request is indisputable.

Comment: @TheMaster [support] won't get this done any faster. Added some tags that might help it get noticed when we do work on these, tho

Comment: @Machavity Just following this wiki: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonym-request/info

Comment: @BhargavRao Thanks for taking care of the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is incredibly confusing.

[Google's own advice](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth_ref) asks users to tag their questions with [google-oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-oauth) if they need help migrating *to* Google OAuth 2.0:

> Important: OAuth 1.0 is deprecated, and we encourage you to migrate to OAuth 2.0 as soon as possible. To get help on Stack Overflow, tag your questions with 'google-oauth'.

But they also seem okay with having questions tagged [google-oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-oauth) even if they're referring to OAuth 2.0.

I suppose this is an incredibly long-winded way to say, yes, we should go about synonymizing these tags, and making [google-oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-oauth) the parent tag.

Comment: I won't accept a Yes answer until synonymisation is performed. I also don’t have the edit privilege to perform that.

Comment: In this scenario it doesn't make sense if you accept this answer anyway.  Synonymization is a fairly slow and laborious process, which should generally be done by the people who are versed in the tag anyway.

Comment: Your link is broke now. Could you update this answer, preferably removingv all the long-windedness with a clear yes(or no)?

Comment: @TheMaster:  My link appears to work, although it redirects *just* to the OAuth 2.0 page instead.  To be blunt, if no one took action about this two years ago when we had a chance to get ahead of the curve, I'm less incentivized to bother editing this to clarify that yes, we should have synonymized these tags eons ago.

Comment: @Makoto Thank you for the reply. I'm interested in reviving this request. I did try to make a synonimization claim, but it says only moderators can make the synonym request when it's just a version number change. If all else fails, I'll edit the second tag to "DO NOT USE" linking this meta.

Comment: @TheMaster:  I'd personally rather you didn't...it doesn't do much

Comment: @Makoto Synonimized Yay!

Answer (score 3):

Currently, Google has no mention of oauth1 in any of it's [identity platform pages](https://developers.google.com/identity/). It is deprecated(2012) and shutdown(2015). The tag [google-oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-oauth) for all intents and purposes refer to oauth2.

Without question, The tag [google-oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-oauth2) should be merged with the parent tag [google-oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-oauth). It needs moderator attention as the  version specific tags can only be synonimised by moderators.